# Permission denied in rootless docker with non-primary group access

Tags: permissions, docker, group

I'm trying to bind mount a directory that is owned by root with 770 permissions. My user is in the group with permission, so I can access it (read, write, & execute) on the host, but the ownership group is not my user's primary group. But when I try to bind mount the directory into a container running in rootless Docker, I cannot access it.

If I set the directory's group ownership to my user's primary group, I am able to access it in rootless Docker.

Is there a way to get access to these directories from my non-primary group?

For example, for a directory like this on the host:

```
drwxrwx---  2 root non-primary-group test-directory
$ id
uid=101(example-user) gid=101(primary-group) groups=101(primary-group),102(non-primary-group)
```

I get denied when running:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v ./test-directory:/test-directory ubuntu
root@1d84f2dsgdsf: # cd /test-directory
bash: cd: test-directory/: Permission denied
```

But if the directory ownership is:

```
drwxrwx---  2 root primary-group test-directory
```

Then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

According to other experiences, this seems the expected situation in the "rootless" version of Docker.

Even if outside the container you have something owned by `user:user`, it seems the rootless Docker will always bind mount using `root:root` inside the container.

Sources:

https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-mounting-permissions-with-user-broken-using-rootless-docker/88257

https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-mount-permissions-unexpected-mounting-as-root-root/129328/6

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

If this additional complexity is not compatible anymore with your workflows, you may eventually also evaluate a rollback to the "traditional" Docker. For example, uninstalling the Docker "rootless", and installing the traditional one.

Comment: Anyway I don't know how to uninstall Docker rootless. Follow-up:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773343/how-to-uninstall-docker-rootless