# How to uninstall Docker "rootless"?

Tags: docker

Premising that nowadays Docker can installed in at least two ways:

1. a traditional mode (to execute `docker` from root, or using `sudo docker`)
2. also a [rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) (to execute docker from non-root and non-sudoer)

Premising that the Docker installer nowadays presents this choice at startup,

Premising that some people install Docker "rootless" by mistake in their current user (example: id:gid `1000:1000`), thinking that "it's the option to run Docker from the normal user with `sudo docker`, and then they discover they picked the wrong choice, and they want to rollback to the traditional version (bonus point: without removing that user),

Premising that some people tries the rootless but then they discover it's not compatible anymore with their workflows, for example because the bind mount is always mounted by `root:root` inside the container:

[Permission denied in rootless docker with non-primary group access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/746953/85666)

Premising that there is sufficient documentation about how to remove a traditional Docker but it seems not enough to uninstall also the rootless version (see this issue with some opinions):

https://github.com/docker/docker-install/issues/166

**Question:**

How to uninstall "Docker rootless"? for example, in Ubuntu, or Debian-based systems?

Purpose: switch to regular Docker. Thanks!

P.S.

I tried various opinions from the mentioned issue, for example by changing "Docker context", but for some reason it was not enough to me. Or anyway, I couldn't figure out what was the minimum sequence by which I achieved my goal. I've followed too many tips from that issue. It would be nice to understand the minimum steps, at least in Ubuntu or Debian-based systems.

Assumption: Docker was installed from the official website.

Extra notes:

- `$HOME/bin/` was unexisting in my environment (so, this was not relevant: https://github.com/docker/docker-install/issues/166#issuecomment-606582544)

Comment: Thanks for any answer. I think this question might be useful to others in the future, more and more, because it happened to a colleague of mine, and we solved it, but we didn't understand very well how. Maybe I will share a solution after I find out. This question is more an attempt to document this case for others, than a concrete question from myself.

Comment: Delete the non-root user that docker was installed under, including its home directory. If you configured it to store its images somewhere else, remove that directory too.

Comment: in your first sentence, you confuse "installing" and "executing". Which do you actually mean?

Comment: @Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI Deleting the user is interesting but it's probably an overkill solution

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm inclined to say that the first phrase "Docker can be installed in at least two ways" is probably somehow correct, since once you install Docker, the Docker installation wizard asks that question (1 or 2) and if you select one of these, Docker is always executed in that way. If you know how to better clarify, edit welcome. Thanks. I tried a bit.

Comment: Ah, that's not a fundamentally different installation, that's just a different kind of operation. You don't uninstall, you reconfigure, probably. But now the problem is that you went with the lesser-supported way of using the manual install instead of a simply `apt install docker` (or `apt install docker-ce`). If you did it this debian/ubuntu way, uninstallation would just be an `apt remove` away. For the binary installer… not so much, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller - I still don't know a suitable rephrase. I think some people will try to land here with the above title. "How to reconfigure Docker to avoid rootless mode?" or something like that? Edit welcome

Comment: I think the details in [the link you provided](https://github.com/docker/docker-install/issues/166) are sufficient.  What problem did you encounter exactly when following those steps?  Alternatively, you could just use your GitHub account to add a comment on that issue, describing the trouble you had and reiterating that it would be helpful to have more official guidance.

Comment: Unless you've made some *spectacularly poor decisions* while installing Docker rootless, deleting the docker user will do exactly what you need.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the user is working with their traditional main user (id:gid 1000:1000) the Docker installation wizard proposes an easy way to setup Docker rootless - for that user. Indeed I agree, that is a poor decision.
That is why some people may want to rollback/uninstall this setup, an I thought it was a reasonable question.